# Two pointers or one pointer + size_t?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a library that needs to work with pointers and I came across an important design choice. Let's say I have a function `do_stuff` that needs to work on a pointer. There are two ways to define such a function
1) `void do_stuff(T* first, T* last)`
2) `void do_stuff(T* ptr, size_t count)`
where `T` names an object type. The first option allows faster iterations. This code

```
for(; first < last; ++first)
    do_stuff_impl(*first);
```

just needs to do a check (`first < last`), and an addition (`first + sizeof(T)`) every cycle while

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    do_stuff_impl(ptr[i]);
```

also have to calculate the address of the object we want to refer to, so one more instruction (`ptr + i * sizeof(T)`) every cycle.
Are there other reason I should prefer the first option over the second one (or vice-versa) in terms of speed, space-efficiency and portability?
Edit: forgot to specify that the second option also need few bytes more to hold a `size_t`
Edit 2: This question is not opinion based at all, I'm not asking for opinion about what I should use (the first one looks better than the second one), I'm asking for facts..

Comment: Is `do_stuff_impl()` really so cheap that the possible slight overhead of indexing every cycle would actually matter?

Comment: did you measure this? I'd be surprised if after compiler optimizations there is any difference between the two. I might be wrong of course, but the only way to find out is to measure

Comment: The point is, there are two ways to do what I want to do, which one should I choose? If there is a faster version I want that, someone using my library could be working on a real-time project or may want to `do_stuff` on millions (or billions) elements. In those cases, every instruction

Comment: choose the one which leads to cleaner code. Your worry about performance is premature optimization

Comment: It's not at all proven that "every instruction counts". Write what makes sense in your codebase, and let them file a bug if they somehow find that it hurt performance later.

Comment: imho without any evidence for a real difference this is purely opinion based. In my opinion you should consider a third option: `void do_stuff(T first, T last)` and allow `T` to be either pointer or iterators

Comment: I would prefer the 2nd way. I don’t think there should be any performance difference in these methods.

Comment: @idclev 463035818 as for me, both ways are clean

Comment: @user7769147 the first can be used with containers `begin` and `end` which is more idomatic than pointer to first element + size

Comment: review amdahls law. Lets say `do_stuff_impl` is 1000 instructions then 1 or 2 more or less to get the array element will not have any impact on overall performance. (Not saying that such optimizations are useless, but you need to put some workload on it and measure)

Comment: Compilers have been compiling these loops to the same code for over two decades.

Comment: GCC [generates](https://godbolt.org/z/C3errd) exactly the same x86 assembly code for the loops.

Comment: So, there are no difference in terms of speed, what about space-efficiency, portability , design or anything else? I have to choose only one of them

Comment: What is the typical use case of `do_stuff`? With a pair of pointers or a pointer and a size?

Comment: I don't understand your edit. A `size_t` is not necessarily larger than a pointer. And it **really** doesn't matter if you had a few more bytes used by one function arg anyway.

Comment: I guess this should be a std::span from C++20.

Comment: @underscore_d the first option hold 2 pointers, the second one 1 pointer and 2 `size_t` and on most platform the size of a pointer is the same as the size of `size_t`

Comment: @idclev463035818 the second can be rewritten to work with all input pointers. All containers provide size. I think we should consider the choice of the arguments in general rather than these particular loop implementations.

Comment: @eerorika indeed, but suppose you get the `last` iterator/pointer as result of calling an algorithm, then calculating the `size` is inear only in case the container does not support random access.

Comment: @idclev463035818 good point in case of sub ranges.

Comment: @erorika you also made some good points but then I wondered why all standard algorithms take two iterators instead of iterator + size and thats the only reason that came to my mind (though a quite convincing one ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Another reason is if the 2nd, 'last' iterator is some significant element, e.g. to iterate/sort/whatever until reaching that. The user doesn't necessarily care at all what is the size of that span; they only want to do some process between those elemtns. I might wager it's more common than specifically caring about a set number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size has the advantage that it is not possible to accidentally pass two unrelated pointers to the function. Sure, it is still possible to pass the wrong size, but the fact that second argument is relative rather than absolute makes that approach simpler.

If we generalise the problem to all iterators, then pair of iterators have the advantage that given arbitrary range of unknown size, there is no need to calculate the distance, which would have linear complexity with non random access iterators, and is not an option for non forward iterators.

The difference between these choices is very subtle, and one is not unambiguously better than the other.

Standard library uses pair of iterators with standard algorithms, while it uses pointer + size with `std::span` and a few string constructors.

My conclusion: Pair of iterators are good for generality, while pointer and size are good for simplicity when generality is not needed or even possible.

---

Note that writing the pair of pointers variant yourself is unnecessary since the standard library already has an algorithm which does exactly that `std::for_each`.

---

Note that once generality is introduced, there is a third option: pass a single object representing the range (by reference). I recommend this approach.

Comment: Re your last edit, yes, and that's what Ranges in C++20 finally give us! \o/ That said, I wonder if most range-type objects can instead just be passed by value; they should just be a couple of iterators. Easier said than done in generic code though. For instance, `range-v3` that I'm looking at now uses forwarding references. That's probably best on balance.

Comment: @underscore_d `I wonder if most range-type objects can instead just be passed by value` Most perhaps, but remember that the good ol' containers are ranges too.

Comment: D'oh, of course! Not just 'proxy' ranges. So yeah, forwarding references are the only way. :-)